# Remove all numbers above 11 in a vector of strings - R

Tags: r, vector

I have a column which includes some data. How can I remove the all numbers above a certain value in that column. Example:

```
Talkative 3
Book Master 16
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Book Master 15
Post Master 20
```

For example in above sample, the result that I want is like:

```
Talkative 3
Book Master
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Grade from Lab 10
Book Master
Post Master
```

Which all numbers above 11 are removed.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a single column or 2 columns

Comment: Actually they were two columns (numbers are in the second column), that I concate them and then I want to remove the numbers above 11. Do you have a better solution? @arkun

Comment: Remove the numbers greater than 11 and then concate e.g. `df <- df[df$value <= 11,]`. If you want to keep the data and then concat, then maybe replace them with a `""` so create a character version of the numeric column e.g. `df$value2 <- as.character(df$value)`. Then update it e.g. `df$value2[df$value > 11] <- ""` and then concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df1$Col1 <- trimws(gsubfn("(\\d+)$", ~ replace(x, as.numeric(x) >11 | 
            as.numeric(x) < 1000, ""), df1$Col1))
df1$Col1
#[1] "Talkative 3"       "Book Master"       "Grade from Lab 10" 
#[4] "Grade from Lab 10" "Grade from Lab 10" "Grade from Lab 10" 
#[7] "Book Master"       "Post Master"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Talkative 3", "Book Master 16", "Grade from Lab 10", 
"Grade from Lab 10", "Grade from Lab 10", "Grade from Lab 10", 
"Book Master 15", "Post Master 20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks @arkun. If I want to delete a range of numbers, for example above 11 and under 1000, How is it going to be?

Comment: @EsterSilva. Updated the post